# how to write nordic characters to a json file from python?

Tags: json, python-2.7, encoding

Suppose I have the following example in python

```
import json

In [46]: d = {'test': u'Fors\xf8g'}

In [47]: print(d['test'])
Forsøg

In [48]: with open('da.json', 'w') as f:
    ...:         json.dump(d, f, sort_keys=True, indent=4)
    ...:
```

Opening that json file I see the following.

```
{
    "test": "Fors\u00f8g"
}
```

But I would like to see it like the print above with the proper nordic characters. How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you see is 100% correct. JSON allows strings that contain only ASCII characters and escape all "extended" characters as `\u` + Unicode character code.

When you or anyone else parses the file again, the correct letter will appear. There is nothing you need to do, really.

If you absolutely don't like how that looks, you need to write the JSON file as UTF-8. This works, too, but Python 2.7's `open()` does not give you a file encoding choice (Python 3+ does).

You can use the `codecs.open()`, which allows easy handling of UTF-8 files:

```
import codecs
import json

d = {'test': u'Fors\xf8g'}

with codecs.open('da.json', 'w', encoding='utf8') as f:
    json.dump(d, f, sort_keys=True, indent=4, ensure_ascii=False)
```

Since `json.dump()` is responsible for the escaped characters, we need to tell it to not do that with `ensure_ascii=False`.